# Why is it called Zman Cheiruseinu (Time of Our Freedom), if we are still slaves of Hashem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, passover

Pesach is called Zman Cheiruseinu (Time of our Freedom) presumably because we were freed from being slaves of Pharaoh. But, the Jewish nation is NOT halachically free to do whatever it pleases. We are still slaves of Hashem, as we say in Shacharis during Berich Shmei, "Anno Avda DeKudsha Brich Hu" (I am the slave of The Holy One Blessed be He).

I heard in a shiur that Pesach is the Yom Tov celebrating our transfer of being slaves of Paraoh to being slaves of HaShem.

Primarily looking for answers/solutions from Rishonim and earlier (e.g. Chazal).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no freeman but one who is occupied in Torah. ([Avos 6.2](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) Everyone is slave to his impulses, Yetzer (desires), but Eved Hashem fulfills his innermost will. The Rambam in Hilchos Gerushin famously writes (regarding 'Hit him until he says "I want!"') that the true and inner desire of every Jew is to do the Torah's will.

Comment: How is it linked with Pesach?

Comment: @kouty because hashem took us out of egypt, on pesach, transfering us from being slaves to the idol-worshipping egyptions, to being His slaves, which is the real ultimate freedom

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to Ari from Ar"i z"l:

1. The Kabbalistic approach distinguishes between referring to Hashem as slaves to referring as sons as many "Pesach-related" Psukim say like:

   > וְאָמַרְתָּ אֶל־פַּרְעֹה כֹּה אָמַר ה' בְּנִי בְכֹרִי יִשְׂרָאֵל׃
   > (... ‘Thus says the LORD: Israel is My first-born son.)
2. While the aspect of slavery to Hashem remained after the Exodus, it is advisable to transcend on Pesach to a higher level of Avodat Hashem, i.g. Bonim, as the Sages prescribe in Avos:

   > ...אל תהיו כעבדים המשמשים את הרב על מנת לקבל פרס** אלא היו
3. The difference is that a slave performs his work solely for the reward, without any affection to his master, while Bonim are driven by their affection to their father.
4. The connection to Pesach is that similarly to Hashem's way of redeeming Bney Israel that was driven "purely" by His affection (hence Shir Hashirim that we read on Pesach, and R"A cried...) and to by any merit of B"I in Egypt, we also should adopt this approach and perform our Avodas Hashem out of deep affection, joy and happiness, without expecting any reward.

*(Adopted from R' Moshe Luria Z"L Beis Gnozay on Shemos).*